# What does `scan` mean in CSS Media Queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

What exactly does the `scan` media features values `progressive` and `interlace` do exactly in simple terms? And are these the only values available for the `scan` feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to do with the output method of the screen of the device.

> Describes the scanning process of television output devices.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#scan).

`progressive` and `interlace` are the only two possible values.

#### Progressive Scan

> Progressive (or noninterlaced scanning) is a way of displaying, storing, or transmitting moving images in which all the lines of each frame are drawn in sequence.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_scan).

#### Interlaced Scan

> Interlaced video is a technique of doubling the perceived frame rate of a video signal without consuming extra bandwidth. Since the interlaced signal contains the two fields of a video frame shot at two different times, it enhances motion perception to the viewer and reduces flicker by taking advantage of the persistence of vision effect.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video).

Answer (score 1):

It is used in style sheets for television. More info (book excerpt) [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=LMN8duabVGcC&pg=PT178&lpg=PT178&dq=css%20progressive%20interlace&source=bl&ots=zvLRBlx9Yt&sig=TAnrCLBkqceFg-OZ6QJ24hk2_vk&hl=en&ei=g4evTfbsBs2BhQet6fyfBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). If Interlaced and progressive videos interest you in some way, you can read about it [here](http://www.allformp3.com/dvd-faqs/38.htm).